# What is "to skip" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

So far, I have neither heard nor thought of a good equivalent of the English *to skip*.

*Preterpasi* is as close as I get, but it doesn't have the same meaning at all.

Translating directly from my native language(Swedish) gives me *transsalti*. Can I use that idiomatically? Is it comprehensible?

Example uses:

- She skipped a year of elementary school.
- Can we skip this part?
- Skipping breakfast is a bad habbit.

Answer (score 7):

*Preterpasi* means to move past, to pass. (Note that PIV does not accept transitive uses of unadorned *pasi* except as an "archaic" equivalent of *trapasi*.)

> *Mi preterpasis lin en la koridoro.* I passed him in the corridor.

I think the usual translation of the English word *omit* is ***preterlasi*** ("let pass"). The mental image is that you are stationary, and the thing slips past you:

> *Mi preterlasis lin en la koridoro.* I let him pass in the corridor.
>
> *Ĉu ni povas preterlasi tiun parton?* Can we omit that part? [lit. "let that part go past"]

However, your own suggestion of ***transsalti*** ("jump over") is perfectly fine, and closer in nuance to the English word *skip*:

> *Ŝi transsaltis jaron bazlerneje.* She skipped a year of elementary school.
>
> *Nu, la sekvantan tagon ni povas transsalti...* Well, we can pass over the next day... [From *Malnova strata lanterno* (H. C. Andersen, tr. Zamenhof)]

Other possibilities are ***salti*** ("to jump", intransitive in Zamenhof's usage):

> *Laŭtlegante, ŝi saltis el la unua al la tria ĉapitro.* Reading out loud, she jumped from the first chapter to the third.

or ***neglekti*** ("neglect"), or ***ignori*** ("ignore"):

> *Ni rajtas neglekti/ignori la duan ĉapitron.* We may disregard the second chapter.
>
> *Neglekti matenmanĝon estas malbona kutimo.* Skipping breakfast is a bad habit.

Comment: Those are some great suggestions! I think most only fit in some contexts that would in English have "skip", not all, but between them one should be able to find one that fits in most cases. Thinking back to skipping grades versus skipping classes, for example; "transsalti" seems fine for skipping grades, but perhaps a bit less so for skipping classes (playing hooky), as in that case there is not so much the sense of skipping to move on to the next as the sense of skipping just to not be in attendance. I'm not sure which option would work best for that one. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: For what it's worth, a short time after this question was discussed, I stumbled upon an example of my own usage where I used *salti* - which is one of your suggestions. En la jena filmeto mi skribis "por Esperanto saltu al 2:40" (https://youtu.be/nLrCWPgT_cI)

Answer (score 4):

For a translation of a book from English into Esperanto that I'm working on, I did translate "skipping" in the sense of skipping classes or skipping grades as "preterpasi", as after some deliberation I could not come up with a better word/translation than that. I think it is fine as a translation, as it is quite obvious what is meant with a slightly figurative/idiomatic interpretation regardless of one's linguistic background, I expect.

Even so, better options might exist. Perhaps something like "nefari" or "neĉeesti" or "ne-io-i", depending on the particular thing you're skipping. In some contexts "maltrafi" might fit.

---

Por traduko de libro el la angla esperanten, pri kiu mi laboras, mi ja tradukis "skipping" sence de preterpasi lecionojn aŭ preterpasi gradojn kiel "preterpasi", ĉar post iom da pripensado mi ne povis elpensi pli bonan vorton/tradukaĵon ol tiu. Mi pensas ke akcepteblas kiel traduko, ĉar sufiĉe klaras kion intencatas per iomete figura/idiotisma interpreto senrespekte al ies lingva deveno, mi pensas.

Tamen povas esti ke pli bonaj ebloj ja ekzistas. Eble io kiel "nefari" aŭ "neĉeesti" aŭ "ne-io-i", depende de la specifa afero, kiun oni preterpasas. En iuj kuntekstoj eble "maltrafi" taŭgas.

Answer (score 2):

I started an answer on this yesterday but got interrupted. I had written:

- Preterpasi, transsalti, ne manĝi

In some contexts, *salti* will work.

In the light of the other answers that have been posted in the meanwhile, I see value in a simple answer to a simple question. Again, if you're doing a lot of translation like this, it's essential to have a good bilingual dictionary.